# org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, cxf

I work on a `Java/Spring/ Apache Cxf` web app and suddenly, I get the error while I made some apparently naive changes,

```
25-Aug-2017 11:48:43.036 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.cxf.common.logging.LogUtils).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
25-Aug-2017 11:48:43.540 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
25-Aug-2017 11:48:43.554 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
[2017-08-25 11:48:43,586] Artifact jaxrs-tutorials:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
25-Aug-2017 11:48:49.258 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/Applications/Tomcat-8.5.16/webapps/manager]
25-Aug-2017 11:48:49.310 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/Applications/Tomcat-8.5.16/webapps/manager] has finished in [51] ms
```

I guess this is the main `info` of the error,

```
25-Aug-2017 11:48:43.540 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
25-Aug-2017 11:48:43.554 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
```

The project structure is provided,

[image]

The `config` directory is utilized for the `Java annotation based config` and code is provided below.

The `AppConfig` file,

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(AppConfig.SERVICE_PACKAGE)
public class AppConfig {

    public static final String BASE_PACKAGE = "mobi.puut";
    public static final String SERVICE_PACKAGE = BASE_PACKAGE + ".services";
    private static final String RESOURCES_PACKAGE = BASE_PACKAGE + ".rest";
    private static final String PROVIDER_PACKAGE = BASE_PACKAGE + ".rest.provider";

    public static final String API_BASE = "/api/*";

    @ApplicationPath("/")
    public class JaxRsApiApplication extends Application {
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public SpringBus cxf() {
        return new SpringBus();
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("cxf")
    public Server jaxRsServer(ApplicationContext appContext) {
        JAXRSServerFactoryBean factory = RuntimeDelegate.getInstance().createEndpoint(jaxRsApiApplication(), JAXRSServerFactoryBean.class);
        factory.setServiceBeans(restServiceList(appContext));
        factory.setAddress("/" + factory.getAddress());
        factory.setProviders(restProviderList(appContext, jsonProvider()));
        return factory.create();
    }

    @Bean
    public JaxRsApiApplication jaxRsApiApplication() {
        return new JaxRsApiApplication();
    }

    @Bean
    public JacksonJsonProvider jsonProvider() {
        return new JacksonJsonProvider();
    }

    private List<Object> restServiceList(ApplicationContext appContext) {
        return RestServiceBeanScanner.scan(appContext, AppConfig.RESOURCES_PACKAGE);
    }

    private List<Object> restProviderList(final ApplicationContext appContext,
                                          final JacksonJsonProvider jsonProvider) {
        final List<Object> providers = RestProviderBeanScanner.scan(appContext, PROVIDER_PACKAGE);
        providers.add(jsonProvider);
        return providers;
    }

}
```

The `WebInitializer` is provided,

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(createWebAppContext()));
        addApacheCxfServlet(servletContext);
    }

    private void addApacheCxfServlet(ServletContext servletContext) {
        CXFServlet cxfServlet = new CXFServlet();

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic appServlet = servletContext.addServlet("CXFServlet", cxfServlet);
        appServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);

        Set<String> mappingConflicts = appServlet.addMapping(AppConfig.API_BASE);
    }

    private WebApplicationContext createWebAppContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(AppConfig.class);
        return appContext;
    }

}
```

I have seen the similar questions to the platform and those don't help me out and I have so little info to solve the issue.

How can I use `logger` to get more info and where I should utilize them? Also, any insight about solving the issue will be helpful. I have updated the `JAR` files with `mvn clean install` and `mvn idea:idea` commands.

`UPDATE`

`Tomcat Localhost Log`

[image]

`Tomcat Catalina Log`

[image]

Comment: There must be stacktraces in your logfile. Add this to your question

Comment: Provide me the reason to downvote and I will either `delete or update` the question

Comment: I have mostly no other `stacktraces`. I have updated the questions with the `Tomcat localhost log` and  the `Tomcat catalina log`

Comment: Maybe you see the Errors only on Console, because of missing logging config `log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.cxf.common.logging.LogUtils).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.` or the missing configuration itself is the problem

Comment: I wrote a detailed answer to the issue. You may like to have a look.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would like to write a detailed answer on the issue and the steps I have followed to solve the problem.

A. There was not enough logging info. I looked up the `POM` and found this,

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

I have excluded the logging in the favour of `SLF4J` and I just deleted the exclusion XML tag to get more logging info. So, it becomes like this,

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

B. Now, I get the logging info. I have this error message like,

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'userService' for bean class [mobi.puut.services.UserServiceImpl] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [mobi.puut.services.UserService2Impl]
```

You get the `ConflictingBeanDefinitionException` for creating the bean with the same name. Though I have some experience with the `Spring`, I need to create with a project with the `Apache Cxf` and hence, clone a demo project for the very purpose. They have the one same entity `User` and same `definition - interface` and same `implementation` of that. Though I have `refactored` to all classes in the project and there seem no apparent errors, I still keep an issue - I keep the same bean name `"userService` in 2 implementations of the interface.

The `User2` class in the entities,

```
public class User2 {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public User2() {
    }

    public User2(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("{id=%s,name=%s}", id, name);
    }
}
```

The `User` class in the entities,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name")
    @Size(min = 5, max = 45, message = "Name must be between 5 and 45 characters.")
    private String name;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(int id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof User)) return false;

        User user = (User) o;

        if (getId() != user.getId()) return false;
        return getName().equals(user.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = getId();
        result = 31 * result + getName().hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The interfaces in the `services` directories,

```
public interface IUserService2 {

    Collection<User2> getUsers();

    User2 getUser(Integer id);

    Response add(User2 user);
}



public interface IUserService {

    List<User> getCurrentStatuses();

    void create(User user);

    List<User> getAllUsers();
}
```

The implementations of the interfaces inside the `services` derectory,

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserService2Impl implements IUserService2 {

    private static Map<Integer, User2> users = new HashMap<Integer, User2>();

    static {
        users.put(1, new User2(1, "foo"));
        users.put(2, new User2(2, "bar"));
        users.put(3, new User2(3, "baz"));
    }

    public UserService2Impl() {
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<User2> getUsers() {
        return users.values();
    }

    @Override
    public User2 getUser(Integer id) {
        return users.get(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Response add(User2 user) {
        user.setId(users.size()+1);
        users.put(user.getId(), user);

        //do more stuff to add user to the system..
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
    }

}


@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements IUserService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDao")
    public IUserDao userDao;

    public List<User> getCurrentStatuses() {
        return userDao.getAllUsers();
    }

    public void create(User user) {
        userDao.saveOrUpdate(user);
    }

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = userDao.getAllUsers();

        if (Objects.isNull(users)) {
            return null;
        }
        return users;
    }
}
```

And, there was the `error` - I annotaed 2 classes with the same bean name of `"userService"`. I had to change it like this to provide the bean a different name,

```
@Service("user2Service")
public class UserService2Impl implements IUserService2 {

    // some code
}
```

And, that error goes away. In short, the error `ConflictingBeanDefinitionException` due to the 2 beans of the same name and I just had to provide a different name.

C. I still had things to fix. Afterwards, when I run the program, I get the

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'mobi.puut.database.IUserDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=userDao)}


// some consequent error messages not necessay to solve the issue

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'mobi.puut.database.IUserDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=userDao)}
```

The error here is `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` and says it can't create a bean with the name of `userService`. OK, this is the code I had and integrated into the project. The Unsatisfied dependency expressed through the field namely `userDao`. `userDao` is the instance of the interface of `IUserDao` and it was `@autowired` like this,

```
    @Autowired
    public IUserDao userDao;
```

Here is more insight of the code,

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements IUserService {

    @Autowired
    public IUserDao userDao;


     public List<User> getCurrentStatuses() {
        return userDao.getAllUsers();
    }

    public void create(User user) {
        userDao.saveOrUpdate(user);
    }

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = userDao.getAllUsers();

        if (Objects.isNull(users)) {
            return null;
        }
        return users;
    }
}
```

I have an interface in the `database` directory and consequent implementation of the interface for the user. The interface name is `IUserDao` and looks

```
soemthing like this, 


public interface IUserDao {

    boolean create(User user);

    void saveOrUpdate(User user);

    boolean create(List<User> users);

    List<User> getAllUsers();

    User getById(int id);
}
```

And, the implementation,

```
@Repository("userDao")
public class UserDaoImpl implements IUserDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    // the HQL queries

}
```

The consequent part of the error message was `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` and the app doesn't find a qualifying bean of the type (class) of `IUserDao`. I have all the `HQL` queries in the implementation of the `IUserDao` and the code works perfectly before.

I have to take a moment to think and finally, I have an intuition that may be the `database` layer is `NOT` integrated into the app. Here is the `configuration` I used,

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(createWebAppContext()));
        addApacheCxfServlet(servletContext);
    }

    private void addApacheCxfServlet(ServletContext servletContext) {
        CXFServlet cxfServlet = new CXFServlet();

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic appServlet = servletContext.addServlet("CXFServlet", cxfServlet);
        appServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);

        Set<String> mappingConflicts = appServlet.addMapping(AppConfig.API_BASE);
    }

    private WebApplicationContext createWebAppContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        // register all the config classes here
        appContext.register(AppConfig.class);
        return appContext;
    }

}
```

Obviously, the no database code is integrated in the `WebInitializer`. I wrote a new class provides all the info of the `database connection` and the `hibernate integration` and looks like,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"mobi.puut.database"})
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {

        //  mobi.puut.entities
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
                new String[]{"mobi.puut.entities"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(
            SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

        HibernateTransactionManager txManager
                = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

        // dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wallet?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Wallet");
        dataSource.setUsername("testuser");
        dataSource.setPassword("testpassword");

        return dataSource;
    }

    Properties hibernateProperties() {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
//        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

And, then finally integrate into the `WebInitializer`. This is the code I used to `registered` the config earlier in the `WebInitializer`,

```
appContext.register(AppConfig.class);
```

Updated the line with the,

```
appContext.register(AppConfig.class, DatabaseConfig.class);
```

Finally, everything works fine. So, the `config` directory looks like,

[image]

`SUMMERY`

I had to solve this problem through the 3 errors,

```
i. ConflictingBeanDefinitionException
ii. UnsatisfiedDependencyException
iii. NoSuchBeanDefinitionException
```

`ConflictingBeanDefinitionException` -> 2 beans with the same name

`UnsatisfiedDependencyException` -> Have a bean `(= "userDao")` in the class which was not correct to use

`NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` -> the code was correct but needed to add the datbase layer in the congig so the `Spring IoC` finds the bean.

I sincerely hope this will help some people.

Comment: Thank you - the tip about the logging revealed a similar issue for me attempting to use a bean in a Spring app. You broke the log jam for me today. :-D

Comment: The beginning of your answer is the key! Thanks! Removing of the exclusion of the `commons-logging` dependency makes Tomcat to write the exception `localhost.YYYY-MM-DD.log` log file. After this, the solving of the problem is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it all starts with the logging output, and since I hadn't a dependency clash, I found that if you create a directory named 'classes' under your 'WEB-INF' folder and create a file named 'logging.properties', you need to add the following lines:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

This will print out the logging into your IDE's console.
In my case, there were multiple ContextLoaderListeners defined.